# PowerShell - Moving a specific Extension to a Year/Month/Extension Folder?

Tags: powershell

I have an old external drive (F:) with lots of folders and files inside.
I want to move all of the files to a new drive (G:).

Will the below structure be possible to achieve?

"Year\Month\by Extension" It can use the original created date..

So 
if I have "`Picture.jpg`" from `15/01/2020` and, if I have "`Document.doc`" from `15/01/2020` then it should go to:

```
G:\2020\01\JPG\Picture.jpg
```

```
G:\2020\01\DOC\Document.doc
```

And so on?

I tried the below and it was able to move to a year folder and a month folder although I noticed the naming of the month folder for January was 1 instead of 01:

https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2015/03/move-files-to-folder-sorted-by-year-and-month-with-powershell/

Any help would be much appreciated, many thanks.

-

Thank you very much for the help, it works pretty well and I was able to copy all the files with ease.

I have been looking at the data, it seems with Copy, it overwrites if there are two files with the same file name hence I adjusted the copy command to move instead for now. Some other changes I made to the destination: extension\year\month format:

```
# Get all files
Get-ChildItem F:\ -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
# Get the modified date
$dt = Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime
$year = $dt.Year
$month = $dt.Month

# This adds "0" in front of the 1-9 months
if($dt.Month -lt 10) {
$month = "0" + $dt.Month.ToString() 
} else {
$month = $dt.Month
}

# Remove leading '.' from the extension
$extension = $_.Extension.Replace(".", "")

# Where we want to move the file
$destinationFolder = "G:\$extension\$year\$month\"

# Ensure full folder path exists
if(!(Test-Path $destinationFolder)) {
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destinationFolder
}

# Copy/Move the item to it's new home
Move-Item $_.FullName $destinationFolder
}
```

This code has been wonderful so far, if it's possible to add the following - it would be complete:

If the "Picture.jpg" already exists in the destination folder, can it be added as "Picture_1.jpg for example so when I review them, I could actually check if it's really a duplicate? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved fairly simply with `Get-ChildItem`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7

```bsh
# Get all files
Get-ChildItem F:\ -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  # Get the creation date
  $dt = Get-Date $_.CreationTime
  $year = $dt.Year
  $month = $dt.Month

  # Remove leading '.' from the extension
  $extenstion = $_.Extension.Replace(".", "")

  # Where we want to move the file
  $destinationFolder = "G:\$year\$month\$extension\ "

  # Ensure full folder path exists
  if(!(Test-Path $destinationFolder)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destinationFolder 
  }

  # Copy the item to it's new home
  Copy-Item $_.FullName $destinationFolder
}
```

Note the space at the end of the `$destinationFolder` variable is purely because Stack Overflow will display the rest of the code as a red string without it. Remove it in your implementation.

Additionally if you need the leading 0 for single digit months, you could do something like:

```bsh
if($dt.Month -lt 10) {
  $month = "0" + $dt.Month.ToString() 
} else {
  $month = $dt.Month
}
```

Comment: You need to change the single quotes in the destination path to double quotes, otherwise the variabes won't get expanded. Also, remove the final backslash so you don't need to add this extra space to overcome the SO limitation. If need be, add `#'# dummy comment` after the line that breaks the SO syntax highlighting. Personally, I would create that path using something like `$destinationFolder = 'G:\{0}\{1:00}\{2}' -f $dt.Year, $dt.Month, ($_.Extension -replace '^\.').ToUpper()`

Comment: @Theo You are correct, good spot. Rookie mistake, has been fixed

Comment: Thanks for this, code worked really good. I noticed after transfer, Destination folder had less files compared to Source and I am pretty sure the reason was because of duplicate filenames. Any chance it can keep the duplicate so I can review later? I amended the main section to show which one I am using - many many thanks!